# Creating Other 3D Primitives in Quil Using Clojure

Tags: clojure, processing, quil

I am working on a Clojure program that is in need of using 3D graphics and for that I am using Quil. The first question I have is are there alternatives using Clojure to Quil? As far as I can tell it seems like the most advanced processing library I could find.

Having asked that, my second question is using Quil (which is based on a Java framework called Processing) what is the best way to add other 3 dimensional primitives. I want to add in a Cylinder, a Cone, and a Torus. I believe my Math and Programming skills are up for the challenge but I need some help on how I should contribute.

First off, if I am to go about adding those primitives, should I add them in Processing or should I add them into Quil? I have been programming for a while but haven't contributed for a bit to open source projects. Having said that, if anyone uses Quil, if I were to use the Vertex commands such as 'begin-shape' in Clojure, would I be able to make a Cylinder with triangle vertices? It says that the shape can not work with 'translate' but would it work with 'with-translation'?

In general I looking for the best way to approach adding 3D primitives to Quil and due to the nature of the code, cannot use Clojurescript so I need to add them for Clojure. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: You can use `Seesaw`, which is a Clojure wrapper over Java's Swing. It gives you access to `Graphics2D` objects to draw onto. The main downside is it requires a fair amount more boilerplate to get up and running, since you have to create a canvas, frame, and set up the `paint` function of the canvas (although that's basically Quil's `draw` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the functions are implemented only for ClojureScript at this time due to a recent migration from a dependency that was no longer being maintained? See [this commit](https://github.com/quil/quil/commit/07bdb283860ff7ab7cbd4204947d12856cd68376#diff-f0ad7f6a779a1344ab45604e40aa2475) and https://github.com/quil/quil/issues/255

Here's a ClojureScript [example of a Torus](http://www.quil.info/sketches/show/3e05f1a7cbab637f8d8941a19a95821a630cd4f38318c6e2f2fab76d7d93a75d).